# Prefill checkbox via link and preserve form function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently have a form i built that is 3 large check boxes, when selected they toggle the continue button below them, https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/demo-select/ this is the link  so you can check it out.

Currently im trying to add functionality to the form that when you click a link from another page, it preselects the checkbox depending on the link selected.

I was able to find a script that allows me to setup a link with a hash ( https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/demo-select/#checkbox1 ) but my issue is that I cannot get the continue button to trigger when the form is accessed this way.

here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = location.hash;

  if(hash=="#checkbox1"){
    $("#checkbox1").prop("checked", !$("#checkbox1").prop("checked") );  // that toggles the checked state
  }
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).on("change", ".mod-link", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(".mod-link:checked").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  })
      if (arr.length > 0) {
      $('#picture').attr('src', '');
    } else {
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/greyBTN.jpg');
    } 
  
  var vals = arr.join(",")
  var str = "/demo/?demo_request_type=" + vals;
  var link = arr.length > 0 ? '<a class="dynabtn" href="'+str+'">Continue</a>': '' ;
  
  $('.link-container').html(link);
  
});

</script>
```

anyone have any idea how i can use links like https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/demo-select/#checkbox1 to trigger that checkbox and still have the continue button toggle on?

Comment: i added Ravis code below but still have errors

Comment: Glad to know that you've resolved the issue and that my fix is "live" on your website :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to toggle the `checked` property, fire a `click` event on your `checkbox`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash) {
    let $checkbox = $(location.hash);
    if ($checkbox.length) $checkbox.click();
  }
});
```

Your `Continue` button will toggle as well.

Comment: That actually works but the only thing now is that the untoggle continue button overlaps the active, Image: https://ibb.co/G7YhFsL is there something missing?

Comment: you can see the error is you use this link https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/demo-select/#checkbox2

Comment: i added a delay and it worked! 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash) {
    let $checkbox = $(location.hash);
    if ($checkbox.length) setTimeout(function () {$checkbox.click();}, 1000);
  }
});

</script>

Comment: @Tetzuro Sorry, I was unavailable to look at your overlap issue, different time zone here.

Comment: @Tetzuro The reason you had to put a timeout is mostly because your `<script>` block comes way before the `<button>` element in the source code. So, when the script executes the button hasn't loaded correctly yet. If you move the block towards the end (just before `<body>` is the standard practice) all the page elements would have loaded by then and you most likely wouldn't face such issues again.